# Diamond shape layout with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to layout an unordered list in a diamond form.

I cannot figure out how to do this without adding hacky `<div>`'s all over the place.

I'd rather keep it semantically a clean `ul`.

Code example (I can add `id`'s, that is no problem.)

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Perhaps something like this can be achieved with `display: flex`? Perhaps `display: table-cell`? I have tried everything so far, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Always 4 boxes? Is their width/height known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layout can be achieved with flexbox all the way through:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;                 /* 1 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;                        /* 1 */
  height: 200px;                          /* 2 */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;                             /* 3 */
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 100%;                         /* 4 */
  display: flex;                      
  justify-content: center;                /* 5 */
  align-items: center;                    /* 5 */
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {   /* 6 */
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;                         /* 7 */
  justify-content: center;               /* 7 */
  align-items: center;                   /* 7 */
}
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
/* grid lines
ul {  border: 1px dashed black; }
li {  border: 1px solid red;  }
*/
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr22qa84/)

Notes:

1. Set the container to `column wrap`.
2. For flex items to know where to wrap, a height must be defined on the container.
3. Remove `ul` default padding.
4. Make list items consume all column space.
5. Center spans vertically and horizontally.
6. Make second and third list items consume half column space, so both fit in one column.
7. Center text vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I appreciate the notes you've included!

Comment: Good answer !  The selector with the double negation seemed a little bit hard to me, and so I came with an alternate way to do the same https://jsfiddle.net/y3v16yr4/  The only difference is that the background of the li now is not covering the whole height

Comment: @vals, the double negation selector was just for the demo. The alternative was two comma-separated selectors. I think I chose the former because it seemed shorter. It's not very important to the answer. Your version also does the job.

Answer (score 6):

I'm interested in seeing if anyone comes up with something a little more clever. Here's the simplest route that came to mind - just using absolute positioning.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

li:nth-child(1) { top: 50%;  left: 0;   transform: translateY(-50%); }
li:nth-child(2) { top: 0;    left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }
li:nth-child(3) { bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }
li:nth-child(4) { top: 50%;  right: 0;  transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great way to do it. I'm being lazy here, I could fiddle it, but why are you using the translate in there? What does it do

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano The translates are to keep the elements properly centered, horizontally or vertically - without the translates, the `top` and `left` properties would only position the elements based on their top-left corner's X/Y coordinates.

Comment: Very neat. Thank you! I'm opting to choose the flexbox based approach as my answer, but this works very well too.

Answer (score 3):

```css
     ul li{
           position:absolute;
        }
        #item1{
         margin-left:10%;
        }
        #item2{
         margin-top:5%;
        }
        #item3{
         margin-top:5%;
            margin-left:20%;
        }
        #item4{
         margin-top:10%;
            margin-left:10%;
        }
```

```html
    <ul >
        <li id=item1>item 1</li>
        <li id=item2>item 2</li>
        <li id=item3>item 3</li>
        <li id=item4>item 4</li>
    </ul>
```

here is my version ... just made it work ... you can find a better way or make it better...

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the 2nd and 3rd `<li>`'s into `<span>`'s and wrap them in a `<li>`:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li > span {
  display: block;
}

li:not(:nth-of-type(2)),
li > span {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>
    <span>item 2</span>
    <span>item 3</span>
  </li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

It's simple, quick, and doesn't require any sort of weird positioning.

To be fully semantically correct, you should technically use an `ol`, since you have an order to your items:

> Usage note: The `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements both represent a list of items. They differ in that, with the `<ol>` element, the order is meaningful. As a rule of thumb to determine which one to use, try changing the order of the list items; if the meaning is changed, the `<ol>` element should be used, otherwise you can use `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I would rather not opt for nested `ul`'s for cleanliness (lists within lists implies there's a sub-ordering, but the sub-ordering is purely visual, not semantic). The list will be used for navigation. Technically that would be ordered, I suppose. Would you use `ol`'s for navigation links when the ordering is purely visual? Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: @user3714447 I'm not exactly what I was thinking at the time, I greatly over complicated it xD See the edited answer, might make it a bit simpler. From what I've read in the MDN docs, if changing the order of an item has no affect on the meaning of the list, then it should be a `ul`. Nobody really cares though, and you'll see the two switched out everywhere based on the dev's preference.

Answer (score 2):

another approach with flex (for info since another one is already given):

```css
ul {
  display:inline-flex;/* or flex + margin:auto for the demo*/
  flex-flow:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:6.25em;/* an height is required to force wraping into columns , mind basic margin, padding and lines wanted /set for li */*/
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:25em;/* whatever you want*/
  background:gray;
}
li {
  display:block;/* removes the bullet */
  padding:0.25em;
  border:solid;
  width:32%;
  margin:0.5em;/* whatever, just mind for ul height*/
  box-sizing:border-box;/* includes padding and borders into height calculation  .... */
}
li:first-of-type,li:last-of-type {
  margin:2em 0;/* increase at least margin-top */
}

body {
  text-align:center;/* to center inline-flex-container and li's text */
}

ul:hover {
  font-size:1.25em;/* see behavior when font-size is different */
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```